# can not call action in Pinia option API

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I am using Vue3 option API and Pinia .

I want to call an action in **Pinia option Api** from component

**component**

```
import { mapActions } from "pinia";
import { useTableStore } from "../../../stores/table";
export default {
  name: "LoggingForm",
  data() {
    return {
      login: {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        serverhost: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
   submit(){
    this.getData(this.login)
   }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapActions(useTableStore, ["getData"]),
  },
};
```

and this is **store/table.js**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import authService from "@/api/auth.js";

export const useTableStore = defineStore({
  id: 'table',
  state: () => ({
    table: []
  }),
  getters: {
    headers: (state) => state.table[0],
    body: (state) => state.table.slice(1)
  },
  actions: {
    async getData1(data) {
     // do something
      }
    },
  }
})
```

But I get this error

[image]

I can Use **state** and **getters** perfectly Just **action** don't work !

what's the problem ?

Comment: The action is actually named `getData1` in `store/table.js`, but you're trying to call `getData()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need

https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#without-setup

In short:

computed => mapGetters

methods => mapActions

You are using mapActions with computed so that will not work